# Using Handbrake with Dropfolders to add subtitle automatically

Tags: video, video-conversion, avi, subtitles, handbrake

I am using Handbrake GUI version and [Dropfolders](http://ctl.du.edu/staff/josephlabrecque/DropFolders/) to execute Handbrake. I was able convert video files successfully without any parameter. It uses default preset I downloaded from [lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/5572037/handbrake-presets-for-your-new-ipad-or-iphone-4). Now I am trying to hard-code the subtitle into the converted mp4 format video. I have tried:

```
-s 1 --subtitle-burn
```

But the handbrake gives me this message and fails:

```
[17:13:36] hb_stream_open: open C:\Subtitle.Eng.srt failed
[17:13:36] scan: unrecognized file type
```

Is there some other option I need to include here? I also do not want to specify the  the subtitle file name so that the the process is automated. Hopefully Handbrake will choose the available subtitle at the specified folder.

The objective here is for me to convert an avi or mkv movies to mp4 format that is optimized for an iPad 2 with subtitles that may be UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (21 Mar 2013), handbrake does not support the burning in of UTF-8 subs. I base this on my own experiences with the failing to encode UTF-8.

To work around use a subtitle editing program (e.g. [Subtitle Edit](https://code.google.com/p/subtitleedit/)).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. UTF-8 is not the main requirement, however. So if I could make handbrake to burn in any subtitle, that would be the start. But at the moment I am considering `ffmpeg` to be the alternative. There is an option to burn in the subtitles and some gluing with bash script for regular expression and cron job (to schedule encoding at off-peak time) should do the job.